How to use a command with @ in its name in a citation postnote?
I am using biblatex and cleveref. I use
\crefname{equation}{Gl.}{Gl.}

to change the

equation (1)

to

Gl. (1)

in the
\cref{eq:oneEquation}

commands (German abbreviation for equation). Additionally, I would like to print citations with a postnote that refers to an equation like this:

Author (Year, Gl. 1)

but the command
\textcite[\makeatletter\cref@equation@name\makeatother~1]{Book}

fails with
% LaTeX Warning: Reference `@' on page 1 undefined on input line 17.
% ??equation@name 1

Using \protect before each command or
\DeclareRobustCommand{\test}{\makeatletter\cref@equation@name\makeatother}

\textcite[\test~1]{Book}

does not help. The only solution I found was
\newcommand*{\crefEquationName}{eq.}

\crefname{equation}{\crefEquationName}{\crefEquationName}

\cite[\crefEquationName~1]{White2006ViscousFluidFlow}

Is there a better solution?
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,hyperref=true,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newcommand*{\crefEquationName}{eq.}
\crefname{equation}{\crefEquationName}{\crefEquationName}

\begin{document}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\test}{\makeatletter\cref@equation@name\makeatother}
\cite[\test~1]{Book}

\newcommand{\testTwo}{\makeatletter\cref@equation@name\makeatother}
\cite[\testTwo~1]{Book}

\cite[\protect\makeatletter\protect\cref@equation@name\protect\makeatother~1]{Book}

\cite[\crefEquationName~1]{Book}

\end{document}


you need to change the catcode outside of commands, before the argument is read, so \makeatletter\textcite[\cref@equation@name~1]{Book}\makeatother. Or

There is also \csname cref@equation@name\endcsname but I wouldn't call it better.

Define an alias in the preamble.
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Book,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={A look to the past},
  year=3200,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,hyperref=true,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcommand*{\crefEquationName}{eq.}
\crefname{equation}{\crefEquationName}{\crefEquationName}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\crefeqname}{\cref@equation@name}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite[\crefeqname~1]{Book}

\printbibliography

\end{document}



Thank you! I will stay with my own solution (\newcommand*{\crefEquationName}{eq.} \crefname{equation}{\crefEquationName}{\crefEquationName}) because it does not require any \makeatletter or \makeatother commands...

Category codes are easily one of the biggest footguns in TeX/LaTeX. When you right, e.g.,
\textcite[\makeatletter\cref@equation@name\makeatother~1]{Book}

the category of @ is going to be determined by its status when \textcite is called so what goes into the optional argument of \textcite is going to be the following:

\makeatletter \cref @other equationletters @other \makeatother ~active 1other

since \makeatletter is not executed until the contents of the argument are interpreted.
If you had written, e.g.,
\makeatletter
\textcite[\cref@equation@name~1]{Book}
\makeatother

the desired result would have been achieved because now @ will be a letter when the argument to \textcite is read.
A similar situation occurs when you tried to define your command. If instead you had written
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\test}{\cref@equation@name}
\makeatother

you would have had the behavior your desired (and defining a command like this would overall be a better design).
